# Number of different quadratic functions mod 12.

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, ring-theory, modular-arithmetic, quadratics

How many different quadratic functions are there of form:

> $x \mapsto ax^2+bx+c \pmod{12}$

All I could come up with is an upper bound of $11*12*12$. This is a puzzle from a [YouTube video by Socratica.](https://youtu.be/87QXdOxeVmU?t=431)

Comment: Note that $6x^2+0x+0$ produces the same function as $6x$, so that function is arguably not a "quadratic" function any more than a function with $a=0$ is. Does this function count?

Comment: @HenningMakholm You're right. I don't know what the definition of a quadratic function in modular arithmetic is then. If it's the same as regular then $6x^2$ still counts and I'd define it that way.

Comment: @HenningMakholm We are counting the total number of different equations right? I'm not getting what you have said with the example $6x^2+6x$..

Comment: @taritgoswami: According to the question we're counting _functions_ -- there are no equations anywhere. The point is that the expression $6x^2+6x$ evaluates to $0$ for every $x\in\mathbb Z/12\mathbb Z$, so it defines the zero function. (And if that means we're counting even the zero function as being a "quadratic function", then the task is simplified somewhat. Then we don't need to special-case coefficient triples with $a=0$).

Comment: @HenningMakholm I think here two functions are *same* when they have same set of roots. So we need to consider the function $6x^2+6x$ into the class of functions where we have all values $\{0,1,2,\cdots , 11\}$ as roots and we will count $1$ for such functions which has all $12$ roots. The number of different such classes will be the answer then. Please correct me if I'm getting it in a wrong way.

Comment: That is not true -- even in $\mathbb R$ the functions $x$ and $2x$ have the same _set of roots_ but are plainly not the same _function_.

Comment: So by brute force I've found $ax^2 + ax = (a+6)x^2 + (a+6)x$ and also $ax^2 + (a+6)x = (a+6)x^2 + ax$ and I highly suspect this is all the combinations.

Comment: @MatthewLiu: More generally you have $ax^2+bx+c\equiv (a+6)x^2+(b+6)x+c$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The map $$\varphi: (a,b,c)\mapsto \bigl[ x \mapsto ax^2+bx+c \bigr]$$ is a homomorphism from $(\mathbb Z_{12})^3$ to $(\mathbb Z_{12})^{\mathbb Z_{12}}$ as groups under pointwise addition. We want to find the number of elements in the *image*
$$ \{ \varphi(a,b,c) \mid a\ne 0 \} $$
Fortunately this is the same as the image of $\varphi$ itself. The requirement that $a\ne 0$ doesn't change the image because we always have $\varphi(0,b,c)=\varphi(6,b+6,c)$ since $6x^2+6x\equiv 0\pmod{12}$ for all $x$. (To see this note that $6x^2+6x=6x(x+1)$ and either $x$ or $x+1$ will be even).

The size of the image of a homomorphism between finite groups is the size of the domain divided by the size of the kernel, so we need to count the number of triples $(a,b,c)$ such that
$$ ax^2 + bx + c $$
is the zero function.

First, of course $c$ must be $0$, because $\varphi(a,b,c)(0)=c$.

Next, calculating modulo $3$ we find that $a\equiv b\equiv c\equiv 0\pmod 3$ because $\mathbb Z_3$ is a field and a nonzero (formal) polynomial over a field can only have as many roots as its degree.

So $a,b\in\{0,3,6,9\}$.

Furthermore, plugging in $x=-1$ gives us $a-b\equiv 0$, so $a=b$. So the only triples that could possibly lead to the zero function are
$$ (0,0,0) \qquad (3,3,0) \qquad (6,6,0) \qquad (9,9,0) $$
We already know that $(6,6,0)$ (and of course $(0,0,0)$) is in the kernel, and plugging in $x=1$ elimintates $(3,3,0)$ and $(9,9,0)$.

In total, the kernel of $\varphi$ is exactly $\{(0,0,0),(6,6,0)\}$, so the size of the image of $\varphi$ is
$$ \frac{12^3}{2} = 864 $$

Comment: We can also calculate $\bmod 4$.  Understanding tgatbthe equivalence which follow are for that midulus, $x\equiv 1$ implies $a\equiv -b$ and $x\equiv -1$ implies $a\equiv b$.  Thereby $b\equiv -b$ forcing $b\in\{0,2\}$.  Then $a\equiv b$ gives $(a,b)\in\{(0,0),(2,2)\}$ which, with the $\bmod 3$ result, identifies the zero images exactly.

Comment: I only don't get the explanation of why $a\equiv b\equiv c\equiv 0\pmod 3$. Why did we change it to working with mod 3?

Comment: @M.Świderski: If $ax^2+bx+c\equiv 0\pmod{12}$ for all $x\in\mathbb Z$, then especially $ax^2+bx+c\equiv 0\pmod 3$ for all $x\in\mathbb Z$. The latter equation is easier to get information out of, because the integers modulo $3$ are a field, so we can exploit our knowledge of how polynomials over a field behave.